# How to continually Parse UDP packets and send to SQL DB in a listener script

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I have a server-side script which constantly listens for UDP data. 
Here is a simple PHP version (found online):

```
<?php

//Reduce errors
error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

//Create a UDP socket
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
  {
  $errorcode = socket_last_error();
  $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

  die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
  }

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0" , 9999) )
  {
  $errorcode = socket_last_error();
  $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

  die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
  }

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

//Do some communication, this loop can handle multiple clients
while(1)
  {
  echo "Waiting for data ... \n";

  //Receive some data
  $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
  echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;

  //Send back the data to the client
  socket_sendto($sock, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
  }

socket_close($sock);
```

I also wrote up a script in Perl which does the same.
I want to parse the UDP messages and store them in an SQL database. 
The UDP data structure basically follows this format; 
 [var1_ID][var1_value],[var2_ID][var2_value],... 
 This structure seems really easy to parse, but I haven't been able to get the variables instantiated yet.
Any help or code response would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the [unpack](http://php.net/unpack) function?

Without knowing more about your packet format (if you give me the C struct information I can convert it for you into an unpack parseable string.), I can't help you much, but you'll want to look at the [pack](http://php.net/pack) function for an the values on how to parse this information quickly. It does use the same SETUP a perl so you should have some idea on how to use it out the box.

On a side note, sockets are not always available, but streams are. You might be better off on the portable code side to use stream functions over socket functions. It's the same thing, but PHP has a built in interface, and socket functions were kind of a bolt on after the fact. (If you ./configure with nothing explicitly enabled then you still get [stream functions](http://php.net/streams), but you do not get [socket functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).)